# Add rows in google spreadsheet based on cell value number answered on google forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm using Form Publisher to join a Google Sheet with a Google Form. I have a question that is answered with a number in the form and it takes you to a different section, depending on the answer.

I would like to add rows in the sheet, also depending on that answer, and fill them with the answers from the next section.

Can this be done?